# Checking user input to see if it satisfies two conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

As part of a larger menu-driven program, I'd like to test user input to see if that input: 
*is an integer* AND
*if it is an integer, if it is within the range 1 to 12, inclusive*.

```
number = 0    
while True:
    try:
            number = int(input("Enter a whole number between 1 and 12 >>> "))
    except ValueError:
            print("Invlaid input, please try again >>> ")
            continue
    else:   
            if not (1<= number <=12):
                    print("Need a whole number in range 1-12 >>> ")
                    continue
            else:   
                    print("You selected:",number)
                    break
```

I'm using Python 3.4.3, and wanted to know if there's a more succinct (fewer lines, better performance, more "Pythonic", e.g.) way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `int` will happily truncate a decimal value. So if you type `3.6`, this code will accept it (as `3`).

Comment: As is, I believe 3.6 would be considered "Invalid input...".

Comment: @smarx, `int("3.6")` would be a ValueError, you would need to cast to float and then to int.

Comment: I stand corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything bar one *if* in the try:

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Enter a whole number between 1 and 12 >>> "))
        if 1 <= number <= 12:
            print("You selected:", number)
            break
        print("Need a whole number in range 1-12 >>> ")
    except ValueError:
            print("Invlaid input, please try again >>> ")
```

Bad input will mean you go straight to the except, if the input is good and is in your accepted range, the   `print("You selected:", number)` and will be executed then we break  or else  `print("Need a whole number in range 1-12 >>> ")` will be executed if is outside the range.

Comment: This code is okay, but I think it's generally better to scope a try/except as much as possible. I like the original code better for this reason.

Comment: @smarx, it is a matter if taste, I find nested code with lots of else blocks pretty ugly and harder to read.

Comment: I don't have sufficient privilege to upvote this yet, but thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty good to me. Minor fix-ups (spelling, indentation, unnecessary `continue`s):

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Enter a whole number between 1 and 12 >>> "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input, please try again >>> ")
    else:   
        if 1 <= number <= 12:
            print("You selected: {}".format(number))
            break
        else:
            print("Need a whole number in range 1-12 >>> ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use isdigit() to check for non-digit characters. Then you shouldn't need to catch the exception. There's only one `if` and it uses operator short-circuiting to avoid doing int(blah) if blah contains non-digits.

```
while True:
    num_str = raw_input("Enter a whole number between 1 and 12 >>> ")
    if num_str.isdigit() and int(num_str) in range(1,13):
        print("You selected:",int(num_str))
        break
    else:
        print("Need a whole number in range 1-12 >>> ")
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need a whole `try`/`except` block. Everything can be fit into a single condition:

```
number = raw_input("Enter a whole number between 1 and 12 >>> ")
while not (number.isdigit() and type(eval(number)) == int and 1<= eval(number) <=12):
    number = raw_input("Enter a whole number between 1 and 12 >>> ")
print("You selected:",number)
```